# Facebook SDK "Purchase" event is sent incorrectly

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-ads-api

We recently switched to automatic "Purchase" event using the Facebook SDK. But since doing so, it seems our "purchase" event appears with warnings claiming our *currency* is missing. In addition, it seems the event isn't marked as automatic in the facebook events debugger console even though we do not send it ourselves.
Any idea on how to debug/resolve this?

Code relevant, Facebook SDK initialization (each in its' relevant app delegate function):

```
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

and for urls:

```
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant code from your app?

Comment: The event is automatic so no code actually appears for it, but I added the FBSDK initialization code for completion sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been found to be an event sent automatically by AppsFlyer. Turning AppsFlyer off fixed the problem.